Parsing pcap in python with pyshark
I'm facing issue where I'm trying to parse http2 packet by using pyshark in python. On my machine everything works fine and i can see all layers but when i tried to run same script in debian docker container with same python and modules i can only see TCP layer and then there is one line saying "DATA".
What i found is, when i run this script on my machine as root i can see only TCP layer as well. I'm not sure if this is right observation or misleading myself.
Does anyone faced same issue?

This sounds more like you missed to install or setup something than a programming issue.

I had same though so I tried multiple times on different images but result was always same.
And as I mentioned in post, when I ran script as root i got same result what i can see in container.

We need a [mre] to be able to answer this. Include details -- which specific version of pyshark is installed in each environment? Which specific version of libpcap? Etc.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
